# Action is not executed

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-auth, zend-controller

Guys am creating an Auth module and inside my `AuthController` I have three methods:

**1.** `loginAction()`

**2.** `autheticateAction()`

**3.** `logoutAction()`

Problem is when I submit the form the `autheticate()` method is not executed :

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('login/process',array('action'     => 'authenticate', )));
```

The exception says 'I must have a view for that action':

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "auth/auth/authenticate"; resolver could not resolve to a file

I just need that method for process submiting data!!!

Inside `loginAction()` I just return form and messages for render and `autheticationAction` is for processing data:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    //if already login, redirect to success page
    if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()){
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('success');
    }
    $form       = $this->getForm();
    return array(
        'form'      => $form,
        'messages'  => $this->flashmessenger()->getMessages()
    );
}
public function authenticateAction()
{
    $form       = $this->getForm();
    $redirect = 'login';
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()){
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()){
            //check authentication...
            $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                                   ->setIdentity($request->getPost('username'))
                                   ->setCredential($request->getPost('password'));
            $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
            foreach($result->getMessages() as $message)
            {
                //save message temporary into flashmessenger
                $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage($message);
            }
            if ($result->isValid()) {
                $redirect = 'success';
                //check if it has rememberMe :
                if ($request->getPost('rememberme') == 1 ) {
                    $this->getSessionStorage()
                         ->setRememberMe(1);
                    //set storage again
                    $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                }
                $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($request->getPost('username'));
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
}
```

**And here my route config:**

```
    'login' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/auth',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'Auth',
                'action'        => 'login',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'process' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Is there a way to not define specific `view` for every action? I really don't need view for this `autheticationAction()`

**Stack Trace:**

```
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(103): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(353): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(328): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\AddskProject\public\index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

Comment: At first glance your code looks ok and it should work (if you return redirect response via `$this->redirect()` there is no need for a view and you don't have to disable it yourself. On thing that I see and can be problematic is that you are using `/login/process` instead of `login/authenticate` in form's action.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `POST` for your form and not `GET`?

Comment: Thanks for answer Wilt. The `/login/process` pointing on my route and route listen `[/:action]`. By default in ZF2 is POST. I will check to `die()` inside `isPost()`

Comment: Yup its `POST` method used.

Comment: And what is `$redirect` value? Does it ever end up at your `return` statement?

Comment: Its not redirected, it just return me exception on submit form. Idk whay? I do this so many times whitout problems...

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown? What does your stack-trace tell you?